# Unable to render classnames based on switch statement in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I am trying to render badges in different colours based on the payment status of an order, but I keep getting a;

```
buttonColour is not defined
```

```
{(() => {
    let buttonColour

    switch (paymentstatus) {
        case "Paid": return buttonColour = "bg-green-100 text-green-800"
        case "Pending": return buttonColour = "bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-800"
        case "Failed": return buttonColour = "bg-red-100 text-red-800"
    }
})()}
<td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
    <span className={`${buttonColour} inline-flex items-center rounded-md px-2.5 py-0.5 text-sm font-medium`}>{paymentstatus}</span>
</td>
```

Comment: i recommend you to learn the basics of react first.

Answer (score 0):

```
{(() => {
let buttonColour

switch (paymentstatus) {
    case "Paid": return buttonColour = "bg-green-100 text-green-800"
    case "Pending": return buttonColour = "bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-800"
    case "Failed": return buttonColour = "bg-red-100 text-red-800"
}
})()}
```

here buttonColour variable block scope end you cannot use this variable outside

```
<td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
<span className={`${buttonColour} inline-flex items-center rounded-md px-2.5 py-0.5 text-sm font-medium`}>{paymentstatus}</span>
```

hence you cannot use buttonColour

It will best for you to keep the logic in seperate hook that will render new buttonColor value when paymentStatus change

`usePaymentStatus.jsx`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function usePaymentStatus(paymentStatus) {
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    switch (paymentStatus) {
      case "Paid":
        setButtonColor("bg-green-100 text-green-800");
        break;
      case "Pending":
        setButtonColor("bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-800");
        break;

      case "Failed":
        setButtonColor("bg-red-100 text-red-800");
        break;
      default:
        setButtonColor("");
    }
  }, [paymentStatus]);
  return {
    buttonColor
  };
}
```

Then inside your App

```
import "./styles.css";
import usePaymentStatus from "./usePaymentStatus";

export default function App() {
  const paymentstatus = "Pending";
  const { buttonColor } = usePaymentStatus(paymentstatus);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
        <span
          className={`${buttonColor} inline-flex items-center rounded-md px-2.5 py-0.5 text-sm font-medium`}
        >
          {paymentstatus}
        </span>
      </td>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a scope issue. `buttonColor` is not accessible in your `span`.

I would suggest a different approach

```
const classes = {
  "Paid": "bg-green-100 text-green-800",
  "Pending": "bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-800",
  "Failed": "bg-red-100 text-red-800",
}
```

and in your `span` use like this -

```
<span className={`${classes[paymentstatus] || ''} inline-flex items-center rounded-md px-2.5 py-0.5 text-sm font-medium`}>{paymentstatus}</span>
```

---

If you want to use a `switch` then create a function  and call that.

**Example:**

```
const getClasses = useCallback( (paymentstatus) =>{

    let buttonColour  = '';
    switch (paymentstatus) {
        case "Paid": 
            buttonColour = "bg-green-100 text-green-800"; 
            break
        case "Pending": 
            buttonColour = "bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-800";
            break;
        case "Failed": 
            buttonColour = "bg-red-100 text-red-800";
            break;
         default:
    }
}, []);
```

In your span use like this

```
<span className={`${getClasses(paymentstatus)} inline-flex items-center rounded-md px-2.5 py-0.5 text-sm font-medium`}>{paymentstatus}</span>
```